# Currying with 3 functions in Scala

Tags: scala, syntax

Im trying to write a function using currying to compute a Collatz series... But im getting lost when trying to write the parameters for `construct6(...)`

```
def c: Int => Int = construct6(isEven)(dec, inc)

//DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE
def construct6: ((Int => Boolean) => (Int => Int, Int => Int)) => (i => (e, o)) = { 
    if (i(n)) e(n) else o(n)
}

def isEven: (Int) => (Boolean) = (a) => (a % 2 == 0)
def dec: (Int) => (Int) = (a) => (a / 2)
def inc: (Int) => (Int) = (a) => (a * 3 + 1)
```

Comment: your function construct6 doesn't even accept a parameter n... I'm not sure exactly what you are asking?

Comment: I need to construct `construct6` that way, so that `c()` can use it.. somehow...

Comment: I think I answered your question to a certain extent... contruct6 still needs to take n: Int.  You can partially apply the curried function with the values to make a function that Int => Int.  Sound like what you are looking for?

Comment: Method `def c: Int => Int = construct6(isEven)(dec, inc)` is given. I need to adapt `construct6` so `c()` can use it...

Answer (score 2):

You're construct6 function MUST take a Int n. Here is the function curried 3 times...

```
def construct6(i: Int => Boolean)(e: Int => Int, o: Int => Int)( n: Int): Int = 
    if (i(n)) e(n) else o(n)
```

When dealing with problems like this it is always important to look at the type signatures and see that they match up.  Notice that construct6 MUST return an Int.  We can doing some functional magic to make a function with a type signature to match Int => Int by doing this:

```
val c: Int => Int = construct6(isEven)(dec, inc)(_: Int)
```

We are partially applying the function you want for i, e, o, and leaving n as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
def isEven: (Int) => (Boolean) = (a) => (a % 2 == 0)
def dec: (Int) => (Int) = (a) => (a / 2)
def inc: (Int) => (Int) = (a) => (a * 3 + 1)
```

you are still missing the n parameter to construct6 (as Andrew Cassidy says). Since you need to curry its parameters, it's more readable if you define construct6 like this (but it's basically the same definition you gave, I just added the n:Int at the end):

```
def construct6 (i:Int => Boolean)(e:(Int => Int)) (o:(Int => Int))(n:Int)
 = if (i(n)) e(n) else o(n)
```

you can now define c as a `Int=>Int` by leaving out the last parameter n to construct6. In the REPL:

```
scala> def c: Int => Int = construct6(isEven)(dec)(inc)
c: Int => Int

scala> c(8)
res0: Int = 4
```

which I believe is what you were trying to do.

If you want to infer c's type instead of specifying it as a `Int => Int` explicitly) you will have to use the omnipresent _ to confirm to Scala that you're not just leaving out anything by mistake:

```
scala> def c2= construct6(isEven)(dec)(inc) _
c2: Int => Int

scala> c2(8)
res1: Int = 4
```

Comment: @AndrewCassidy: sorry, I didn't notice that my answer is now a duplicate of yours!

Comment: It's cool! I still upvoted you.  The slight differences may be valuable to someone : ).  In particular the _

Comment: @AndrewCassidy ...which by the way I just realized is not even strictly needed if you give the type of c explicitly. Still mostly a duplicate though. I would just integrate your answer with whatever you believe is missing and I can delete mine